# Scientist discovers that Earth isn't in space

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to recall the title of a  movie. A scientist find that earth / space is molecular/atom-sized and space had borders.

It should be funny scifi. And I am also not sure if the main story is like this. It should be like in rick and morty earth in earth in earth.

Two guys just talked next to me.
I dont have more informations.

Comment: By 'funny' do you mean that it was a comedy or that it was peculiar/odd?

Comment: What does "*also not sure if the main way is like this*" mean? Can you explain that in different words?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Live action or animated?

Comment: Could be they were talking about this https://youtu.be/nky0_iK-9F4?t=60 (i.e. MIB)

Comment: I know MIB. But Its diffrend movie.  i know i dont have lot of informations about it. 

I Just tried to move up my chance to find movie here 